# Combine grep -f and awk

Tags: awk, grep

I am using two commands:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' SomeFile.txt > Pattern.txt

grep -f Pattern.txt File.txt
```

With the first command I create a list of desirable patterns. With the second command I extract all lines in File.txt that match the lines in the Pattern.txt

My question is, is there a way to combine awk and grep in a pipeline so that I don't have to generate the intermediate Pattern.txt file?

Thanks!

Comment: Be very careful when you use the word "patterns" as that term has no specific meaning and therefore is open to interpretation. Be clear - are you talking about matching strings or regexps or something else? Do you want to match on the whole line/word or parts of a line/word? Show some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this all in one invocation of awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}{for(i in a)if($0~i)print}' Somefile.txt File.txt
```

Populate keys in the array `a` from the second column of the first file. `NR==FNR` identifies the first file (total record number is equal to this file's record number). `next` skips the second block for the first file.

In the second block, loop through all the keys in the array and if the line matches any of them, print it. To avoid printing the line more than once if it matches more than one pattern, you could add a `next` here too, i.e. `{for(i in a)if($0~i){print;next}}`.

If the "patterns" are actually fixed strings, it is even simpler:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$0 in a' Somefile.txt File.txt
```

Comment: Looks better to use `awk` for what it can do and save the `grep` process at all! +1

Answer (score 3):

If your shell supports it, you can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
grep -f <(awk '{ print $2 }' SomeFile.txt) File.txt
```

`bash` and `zsh` will support that, others will probably too, didn't tested.

---

Simpler as the above and supported by all shells would be to use a pipe:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' SomeFile.txt | grep -f - File.txt
```

`-` is used as the argument to `-f`. `-` has a special meaning here and stands for `stdin`. Thanks to [`Tom Fenech`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212476/combine-grep-f-and-awk/29212541?noredirect=1#comment46635247_29212541) for mentioning that!

Comment: This looks nicer than all in awk +1

Comment: If process substitution is unsupported, I think you can do `awk '{print $2}' SomeFile.txt | grep -f - File.txt`

Comment: @JID Also handy in many other situations, like `diff <(command) <(sleep 1;command)` or whatever..

Comment: @TomFenech Sure, you are right! I made it to complicated!!

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl! This is the kind of one-liners I love! I did try process substitution and didn't work...

Comment: You are welcome. process substitution should not being used in shell scripts since it isn't supported by many shells. However if you explicitly launch a `bash` it should work. Also have a look at Tom's approach using `awk` only.

Comment: @Yorgos the problem with loving "one-liners" is you end up with a collection of well-loved but single-use one-liners and have to ask for a new one-liner for the next problem you encounter instead of just learning one question/answer at a time how to write general-purpose text processing code in awk so you can solve all of your future problems too.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree in part with what you say, but I believe that one-liners can also be generalised and solve many different problems. What I wanted to say is that if I can avoid a loop by using a one-liner, I will do so.

Comment: Note that there is a [bug in `grep -f`](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?16305) that will make this _very slow_ when you have more than a ~hundred queries.  The [full `awk` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29212744/519360) doesn't suffer from that.  The plain text `awk` solution (in that same answer) is considerably faster than using `grep -xFf` as well.

Comment: @AdamKatz Thanks for the comment. Much appreciated